# How can I Adjust view height to be below navigation bar in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I created a WKWebView in code and added it to my view.

```
override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}
```

When the webpage opens I can see that my navigation bar from the previous view is blocking some of my webpage.

How can I adjust the view in code to make my webpage appear below my navigation bar?

[image]

Comment: You need to put constraints on your webView, so that it would be below the top bar.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Constraints didn't occur to me until you mentioned it. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a top constraint to your webview and give it a constant value that works for you (in case you want to add a margin)

```
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
```

You should also add the remaining anchor values.

```
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Comment: No worries.. :)